# Binary search in Java - learning it "my way"

Tags: java, binary-search

So I'm trying to teach myself how to implement a binary search in Java, as the topic might have given away, but am having some trouble.

See, I tend to be a little stubborn, and I'd rather not just copy some implementation off the internet.

In order to teach myself this, I created a very (VERY) rough little class which looks as follows:

```
public class bSearch{

/**
 * @param args
 */

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int one = 1;
    int two = 2;
    int three = 3;
    int four = 4;
    int five = 5;
    int six = 6;

    ArrayList tab = new ArrayList();

    tab.add(one);
    tab.add(two);
    tab.add(three);
    tab.add(four);
    tab.add(five);
    tab.add(six);

    System.out.println(bSearch(tab, 53));

}

@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
public static int bSearch(ArrayList tab, int key) {

    if (tab.size() == 0)
        return 0;

    if ((int) tab.get(tab.size() / 2) == key)
        return key;

    ArrayList smallerThanKey = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList largerThanKey = new ArrayList();

    for (int i = 0; i < (tab.size() + 1) / 2; i++) {
        smallerThanKey.add(tab.get(i));
    }

    System.out.println("Smaller array = " + smallerThanKey);

    for (int i = (tab.size() + 1) / 2; i < tab.size(); i++) {
        largerThanKey.add(tab.get(i));
    }

    System.out.println("Larger array = " + largerThanKey);

    if (key < (int) tab.get(tab.size() / 2)) {
        bSearch(smallerThanKey, key);
    } else {
        bSearch(largerThanKey, key);
    }

    return key;
    }
}
```

As you can see, it's pretty far from beautiful, but it's clear enough for a noobie like myself to understand, anyway.

Now, here's the problem; when I feed it a number that is in the `ArrayList`, it feeds the number back to me (hurray!), but when I feed it a number that's not in the `ArrayList`, it still feeds me my number back to me (boo!).

I have a feeling my error is very minor, but I just can't see it.

Or am I all wrong, and there is some larger fundamental error?

Your help is deeply appreciated!

***UPDATE***

Thanks for all the constructive comments and answers! Many helpful pointer in the right direction by several of you. +1 for everyone who bumped me along the right path.

By following the advice you gave, mostly relating to my recursions not ending properly, I added a few `return` statements, as follows;

```
if (key < (int) tab.get(tab.size() / 2)) {
     return bSearch(smallerThanKey, key);
} else {
     return bSearch(largerThanKey, key);
}
```

Now, what this does is one step closer to what I want to achieve.

I now get `0` if the number is nowhere to be found, and the number itself if it *is* to be found. Thus progress is being made!

However, it does not work if I have it search for a negative number or zero (not that I know why I should, but just throwing that out there).

Is there a fix for this, or am I barking up the wrong tree in questioning?

Comment: Not quite related, but you should *really* be using generics... Also, have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: If you are a newbie as you say, one lesson first: never suppress warnings as a newbie, you might get in trouble with this

Comment: @user3580294 True, but I just typed this up quickly and haven't really read up on generics just yet, and I just wanted to get a rough idea for binary search, so I let stuff like that slide. But you're right, in the long run, I'll probably be better off learning how to use it.

Comment: @ZerO Noted. I'll be careful of that in future code. Guess it's better to be told what's wrong than spend hours guessing, huh?

Comment: Binary search is useless in list: because you don't have direct access.
Binary search is useless if you do a hard copy of your array.
I know you're just learning, but i think those are the most important errors.

Comment: Basically, the solution to the "I want to store negatives/zeros" is to have the method return the index of 'key' inside 'tab', or '-1' if it is not found. Please take a look at my (updated) answer, below. It addresses this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT

Just as a quick solution to the exact question you're asking: you need to change the last few lines to the following

```
  if (key < (int) tab.get(tab.size() / 2)) {
      return bSearch(smallerThanKey, key);
  } else {
      return bSearch(largerThanKey, key);
  }
}
```

Having said that, let me point out a few more issues that I see here:

(a) you can use generics. That is use `ArrayList<Integer>` rather than just `ArrayList` this will save you from all those casts.

(b) Instead of returning the value that you found you'd be better off returning the index in the ArrayList where the value is located, or -1 if it was not found. Here's why: returning the `key` provides the caller with very little new information. I mean - the caller already known what key is. If you return the index to the key you let the caller know if the key was found or not, and if it was found where in the list it resides.

(c) You essentially copying the entire list each time you go into `bSearch()`: you copy roughly half of the list into `smallerThanKey` and (roughly) half into `greaterThanKey`. This means that the complexity of this implementation is not `O(log n)` but instead `O(n)`.

(EDIT #2)

Summarizing points (a), (b), (c) here's how one could write that method:

```
public static int bSearch(ArrayList<Integer> tab, int key) {
  return bSearch(tab, 0, tab.size(), key);
}

public static int bSearch(ArrayList<Integer> tab, int begin, int end, int key) {
    int size = end - begin;
    if (size <= 0)
        return -1;

    int midPoint = (begin + end) / 2;
    int midValue = tab.get(midPoint);
    if (midValue == key)
        return midPoint;

    if (key < midValue) {
        return bSearch(tab, begin, midPoint, key);
    } else {
        return bSearch(tab, midPoint + 1, end, key);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I added a second method that takes a `begin`, `end` parameters. These parameters let the method which part of the list it should look at. This is much cheaper than creating a new list and copying elements to it. Instead, the recursive function just uses the list object and simply calls itself with new `begin`, `end` values.

The return value is now the index of the `key` inside the list (or -1 if not found).

Comment: why downvoted ? he is just trying to help the guy find the error . Isn't that the question ??

Comment: @RamanSingh Because this doesn't fix the problem. This just means that the method will return 0 in pretty much every case.

Comment: @user3580294 But the person asks that even if the key is not present in the list , it still returns the key . So this post helps him figure out that reason . Is he supposed to edit his code and make his work ? No . He is just guiding him . Really no need to downvote this answer .

Comment: @RamanSingh Sure, but if OP implements that solution he/she might as well come back with "my binary search implementation returns `0` every time". It's not really addressing OP's problem more than just changing how it shows up... But the point is moot now that the post is edited.

Comment: I wished to thank you personally, for clarifying my errors in a way I could understand and providing an example of how it should be done. My hat's off to you, sir!

Answer (score 1):

Your recursion is not properly ended. At the end of the method you recursively call the `bSearch`method for the left or right part of the array. At that point you need to return the search result of the recursive calls.

The idea of the binary search is: If your current node is not the `key`, look at the left if the value of the current node is bigger than the `key` or look at the right if it is smaller. So after looking there you need to return the search result from there.

```
if (key < (int) tab.get(tab.size() / 2)) {
    return bSearch(smallerThanKey, key);
} else {
    return bSearch(largerThanKey, key);
}
```

As a side remark, have a look at `System.arraycopy` and it is always a good idea to not suppress warnings.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* the issue is here:

```
if (key < (int) tab.get(tab.size() / 2)) {
    bSearch(smallerThanKey, key);
} else {
    bSearch(largerThanKey, key);
}

return key;
```

You're just throwing away the result of your recursive call to `bSearch` and returning `key`. So it isn't really much of a surprise you get back whatever number you feed into the method.

Remember how binary search is supposed to work -- if the value isn't in the middle, ***return* the result of searching in the left/right half of the array**. So you need to do *something* with those recursive calls....

And with binary search, you really should be more concerned about finding the *location* of whatever you're looking for, not its value -- you know that already! So what you *think* was the binary search working right was a bit mistaken -- searching for `1` should have returned `0` -- the index/location of `1`.

Also, you shouldn't need to deal with copying arrays and such -- that's an operation that is unnecessary for searches. Just use parameters to indicate where to begin/end searching.